# When I open my project, I get this message: "This solution is offline. [Team Foundation //https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/tfs/applications"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

This solution is offline.  [Team Foundation Server: http://xxxxxxxxxx/tfs/applications]
The solution was offline during its previous session and will remain offline.

What kinds of problems would cause the above error?
And when this happens, there is no check-in option and trying to save individual files results in a message that says the file you're trying to save is write protected. Do you wish to override? I can still save files by responding "yes." But all this is very confusing and dangerous. What causes this condition?

Comment: I am not a TFS guru (you could have added that tag BTW), but you might start here: https://glumesc.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/visual-studio-2008-the-solution-was-offline-during-its-previous-session-and-will-remain-offline/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What kinds of problems would cause the above error?

I assume you're using a non-`git` TFS workspace (i.e. using TFS' old-school centralized source-control service that essentially is Microsoft's not-invented-here take on SVN.

TFS workspaces come in two flavours: ["Local" and "Server"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops). A "Local" workspace is *kinda* like a git repo in that it allows you to make check-ins while working offline but it has limitations. A "Server" workspace requires you to have an active and reliable connection to the TFS server and you cannot make check-ins while disconnected (you can still make changes, of course, but you can't save them to TFS).

I assume you have a "Server" workspace instead of a "Local" workspace, hence the error message.

> And when this happens, there is no check-in option and trying to save individual files results in a message that says the file you're trying to save is write protected.

Correct. But you can always remove the Read-only flag on your files in the filesystem and edit the files and do a manual sync to make a TFS check-in after you've reconnected. The files are marked as Read-only because TFS is designed around locking files and checking-out files from source-control, so it wants to discourage you from editing files that haven't been checked-out. If you do edit a file that hasn't been checked-out you can still include it in a check-in but you need to retroactively check it out when you reconnect to the TFS server.

> I can still save files by responding "yes." But all this is very confusing and dangerous.

It's not really dangerous - the whole point of a version-control system is to get the freedom to make arbitrary changes and be able to rollback (or branch) whenever you want (except doing so using TFS rather than `git` (especially when offline), is just a rather huge PITA).

To resolve this situation:

- Open Visual Studio (you don't need to open a project/solution first).
- Assuming you're using VS2015 or later, open Team Explorer.
- Ensure Team Explorer is in TFS mode instead of `git` mode:

  - When in git mode you'll see buttons like "Changes", "Branches", "Sync" which have a red highlight.
  - When in TFS mode you'll see buttons like "My Work", "Pending Changes", and "Source Control Explorer".
  - If it's in git mode, switch to TFS mode by clicking the Connect button in the tool windows' toolbar at the top and select your TFS server.
  - You may also need to go Tools > Options > Source Control > Current plugin: "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server".
- After reconnecting to TFS, reopen your project/solution.
- VS should detect that you made changes while offline and offer to create a pending check-in for you (and automatically check-out any edited files). If not, open "Source Control Explorer" and manually run the "Compare Folders" tool and check-out any files it detects as changed before making your new check-in.
- You may also need to go File > Source Control > "Go online"

Here's a screenshot from Visual Studio 2008 (it's the only screenshot I could find, sorry - but the menu layout is identical):

[image]

After you've done this and made your check-in, it's very important that you visit your local fishmonger and buy a large trout, then visit your project manager and give them a jolly good slapping with it for requiring their team to use TFS in 2020. Even Microsoft uses git internally.

Comment: Can I use a whale and a crane to do the slapping? :)